# LINQ to Entities error using SequenceEqual enumerable method

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ statement (stationId is an int and version is a byte array):

```
            var foundStation = (from wd in _Context.AssignmentWizardDatas
                from station in wd.AssignmentWizardStationDatas
                where station.Id == stationId
                where station.Version.SequenceEqual(version)
                select station).SingleOrDefault();
```

When the above code is run I encounter the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SequenceEqual[Byte](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Byte])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

After a bit of reading I am aware that the problem is LINQ cannot convert the SequenceEqual method call into a SQL equivalent (I think anyway).  Does anyone know of a workaround solution for this?  Or perhaps could point me in the right direction when trying to use byte arrays with LINQ queries, I couldn't find an existing question specifically to do with byte arrays.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Using Jani's post this was the final code used to resolve this error:

```
        //eager execution of the linq query to find the stations 
   var foundStation = (from wd in _Context.AssignmentWizardDatas
                            from station in wd.AssignmentWizardStationDatas
                            where station.Id == stationId
                            select station).ToList();
   //finding the result in memory   
        var result = (from f in foundStation
                      where f.Version.SequenceEqual(version)
                      select f).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//eager execution of the linq query to find the stations
var foundStation = (from wd in _Context.AssignmentWizardDatas
                    where wd.Id == stationId
                    select station).ToList();
//finding the result in memory  
var result = from f in foundStation 
             where f.version.SequenceEqual(version)
             select f;
```

Comment: Thanks Jani, did you try this?  For me this still raises the same exception?

Comment: But when you change the code to this, the exception that could ocuured has nothing to do with `LINQ to Entities`, it will be executed in memory. Are you sure about that?

Comment: thanks.  I have looked again I don't think I included the .ToList() on the end of the first LINQ statement.  I have updated my orginal question to show the final answer I used as it is slightly different to what you wrote here.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MattStacey: You are going down the wrong road - changing the way you query EF and materializing all results into memory just so your unit tests pass is a really, really bad approach. Don't expect this to scale even though it technically "works" right now.

Answer (score 8):

You are correct in the way you interpret the error, but you don't need `SequenceEquals()` at all - you can directly compare the byte array provided you bind to `varbinary(MAX)` in the DB.

```
var foundStation = (from wd in _Context.AssignmentWizardDatas
from station in wd.AssignmentWizardStationDatas
where station.Id == stationId
where station.Version == version
select station).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: yep you are right when I run the website this works as expected. I am working in a TDD environment and am now a little confused as I did have this code originally but changed it as it causes my unit tests to fail, whereas using the SequenceEqual method actually passes the unit tests but hits exception at runtime.  Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @MattStacey: that makes sense - in your unit test `SequenceEqual()` will work on two byte arrays, but if you compare directly you are comparing only the references, so they will never match. It's very tough to unit test EF w/o actually hitting the DB because they are many differences you will have to account for.

Comment: I've verified this works. We ran into the same issue using NHibernate, Fluent, and Linq2NH. Converted to a simple "e.ssn == ssn" where both ssn is a varbinary and a byte[] and it started working. I assume Linq2NH understands the comparison and converts it to appropriate HQL which understands the mapping+parameter type combo and converts to proper SQL.

Comment: This does not work (now) in nHibernate. Using entity.ByteArrayProperty.Equals(somebyteArray) or entity.ByteArrayProperty == somebyteArray both fail with a querysyntax / mismatchedtreenodeexception. I can see from the emitted hql that nHibernate tried to create a x IN (,) expression where all the values in the byte array became params for IN expression. However this works with QueryOver, just not linq.

Answer (score 2):

9 years later but... LINQ support for `SequenceEqual` was added to EF Core 5.0, in addition to `Length` and `Contains`.

See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#query).

Comment: I am having this issue - stuck in .Net Framework 4.8